# How to add a body class based on a custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, css

I'm trying to insert the slugs of custom taxonomies as classes in the opening body tag on certain WordPress pages. What I have so far is causing errors.

I found a bit of help with the examples [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms#A_Basic_Example) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), and it works, except that it gives an error on any page that doesn't have a term from the "section" taxonomy.

The error is:

```
Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/*****/public_html/example.com/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 387
```

and the code is:

```
// add classes to body based on custom taxonomy ('sections')
// examples: section-about-us, section-start, section-nyc
function section_id_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    $section_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'section');
    if ($section_terms && !is_wp_error($section_terms)) {
        $section_name = array();
        foreach ($section_terms as $term) {
            $classes[] = 'section-' . $term->slug;
        }
    return $classes;
    }
}
add_filter('body_class', 'section_id_class');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the job of `$section_name`? Also you must get an return; you if statement kill the default return. It is important, if your if statement fails.

maybe this works, but not tested, write from scratch.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'section_id_class' );
// add classes to body based on custom taxonomy ('sections')
// examples: section-about-us, section-start, section-nyc
function section_id_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    $section_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'section' );
    if ( $section_terms && ! is_wp_error( $section_terms ) ) {
        foreach ($section_terms as $term) {
            $classes[] = 'section-' . $term->slug;
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: So you just moved the add_filter() to the top? That did work. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes, is the same for functionality, but not for codex of WP.
Process: got to hook `body_class` and include function `section_id_class` --> use the functions. The idea for this spelling style.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal you'll get errors for pages that are not association with the section.
Make sure you also return a '$classes' if your 'if-statement' fails.

In other words, make sure you add an else here.

```
// add classes to body based on custom taxonomy ('sections')
// examples: section-about-us, section-start, section-nyc
function section_id_class($classes) {
global $post;
$section_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'section');
if ($section_terms && !is_wp_error($section_terms)) {
    $section_name = array();
    foreach ($section_terms as $term) {
        $classes[] = 'section-' . $term->slug;
    }
else 
{  $classes = 'default-class'; }
return $classes;
}
}
add_filter('body_class', 'section_id_class');
```

something like this

Comment: on this example yous kill the default classes from WP and also the classes from other plugins or theme.

Comment: I agree, but that was why you got the error. You should make sure the replacement is only called for terms with section then. instead of on all. and drop the else then. and add filter when needed